# Constant expression required error on the switch case for onRequestPermissionResult

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm writing a simple code for asking for location access

```
 private static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_device,container,false);

    // fragment manager for passing values
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    // checking location permission and asking for permission
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if(permissionCheck != 0){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
    }
```

when I call the onRequestPermissionsResult fuction and apply a switch case on the request code, the compiler shows an error 'constant expression required'

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

what might be the problem?
Please note the oncreateview is copied here completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION` final, and your problem will be solved:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
```

In **case** statement you **must** always have final value.